# Same Origin Policy and CSRF-Tokens

Tags: csrf, same-origin-policy, cors

If we trust browsers that they satisfy Same Origin Policy without bugs, would we still need CSRF-tokens?

Assuming server doesn't have CORS enabled:
As far as I know we are not allowed to do POST requests cross-origin, then why is there a CSRF token?

If server has CORS enabled: (assuming both GET and POST, because I don't see the point of CORSing POST but not GET)
We could GET the page, read the token and POST a correct request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If we trust browsers that they satisfy Same Origin Policy without bugs, would we still need CSRF-tokens?

Yes, we will. Due to the fact that there are other requests that don't fall under SOP like form submit, loading scripts..etc

> Assuming server doesn't have CORS enabled: As far as I know we are not allowed to do POST requests cross-origin, then why is there a CSRF token?

Even when CORS is disabled, the browser will complete XHR POST requests, the attacker won't be able to access the response, but the request will be completed and a he will successfully accomplish the CSRF attack.
This, however, will fail in case of `PUT` , `PATCH` and `DELETE` requests since the browser will first issue an `OPTIONS` request to the request endpoint to verify the request.

> If server has CORS enabled: (assuming both GET and POST, because I don't see the point of CORSing POST but not GET)
>   We could GET the page, read the token and POST a correct request.

This would be a vulnerability with the server itself. CORS should not be open to all remote hosts, only the ones you own (trust).